# JSP Refresh Page Header

Tags: jsp, header, refresh

```
 <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

<% 
//code here to check user login
%>

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

How can I refresh the header page (which displays a welcome message) inside the code  which checks user login (I don't want to refresh the whole page already tried that just the header.jsp)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. Best way to solve it is by creating a servlet which handles all login code and then send a `response.SendRedirect()` back to this page.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. It's too late. JSP writes to the response directly while executing the code in scriptlets. Just rearrange the code logic. You should perform business logic before emitting any HTML.

```
<% 
    // Code here to check user login and prepare variables.
%>

<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

<% 
    // Code here to print necessary HTML based on prepared variables.
%>

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

If you was using a normal [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) the MVC way, you'd never have faced this problem.